# Get Percentage of Blank CSV Rows

Tags: csv, powershell

I've got a section of a PowerShell script that imports a CSV and uses `Measure-Object` to do some math on the imported values grouped by host.  I'm currently getting the count of lines pertaining to the host, the minimum, maximum, and average of the values.  Snippet below:

```
$data = Import-CSV -Path $SummaryTemp
$collection = @()
$data | Group-Object Hostname | ForEach-Object {
    $datarow = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Hostname = $_.Name }
    $stat = $_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Latency -Minimum -Average -Maximum

    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Count" -Value $stat.Count
    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Minimum" -Value $stat.Minimum
    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Average" -Value $stat.Average
    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Maximum" -Value $stat.Maximum

    $collection += $datarow
}
$collection | Export-Csv -Path $StatsCSV -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

The imported CSV would look something like this:

```
"Hostname","Latency","DateTime"
"test1","22","2016-07-01 14:13:50"
"test2","28","2016-07-01 14:13:54"
"test1","","2016-07-01 14:14:02"
"test2","27","2016-07-01 14:14:06"
```

The value I'm running the math on can also be `$null`, so non-existing in the CSV like [test1] above.  The problem I'm having is that I'd like to also calculate the percentage of lines that are blank.  For example, the above CSV would be 50% for test1 and 0% for test2.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could look like this

```
...
$data | Group-Object Hostname | ForEach-Object {
    $datarow = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Hostname = $_.Name }
    $stat = $_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Latency -Minimum -Average -Maximum
    $emptyStat = $_.Group | ? { $_.Latency.Trim().Length -eq 0 } | Measure-Object
    $emptyLinePct = "{0}%" -f ($emptyStat.Count * 100 / $stat.Count)

    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Count" -Value $stat.Count
    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Minimum" -Value $stat.Minimum
    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Average" -Value $stat.Average
    $datarow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Maximum" -Value $stat.Maximum
    $dataRow | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Empty" -Value $emptyLinePct

    $collection += $datarow
}
...
```